# Pixelated Icon when rendered

Tags: android, kotlin, icons

I am working on an app that's a social media app. I have my icon but it's pixelated.  I was wondering how I could clear that up. I have never had this issue before. The login screen has the logo and it's the same logo for the icon. I am assuming the icon cannot handle the image.

---

[image]

Here is the icon:

[image]

Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: If this is a raster icon, did you include it at all the different resolutions necessary? If you just included one huge image, there will be resizing artifacts like this from it being shrunk down without mip mapping.

Comment: @tenfour04 I am not too worried at the moment with the icon. I was just getting tired of the android icon. But the image was a royalty free image I am using. So I have not really tried an icon this fancy before. This is a new social media platform I am building so the icon is unique. Like Facebook has a simple icon. But everyone knows that icon. That's what I am shooting for. So hopefully I can get it squared away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you're trying to render a high res image as an icon

Use an online formatter like [Appicon](https://appicon.co/) to convert that image to lower res and then use that newly created image as the icon

Answer (score 0):

Try using SVG format for the icon